# Adding a node using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have an HTML string (for instance `<div class="input">hello</div>`) and I want to add a node only if the HTML tag in the string is a `label` (for instance `<label>Hi</label>`).

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(html)

doc.children.each do |node|
  if node.name == 'label'
    # this code gets called
    span = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new "span", node
    span.content = "hello"

    puts span.parent 
    # nil

    span.parent = node
    # throws error "node can only have one parent"
  end
end

doc.to_html # Does not contain the span.
```

I cannot for the life of me understand what I'm doing wrong, any help would be **greatly** appreciated.

**Edit**: This solved my problem, thanks for the answers!

```
# notice DocumentFragment rather than XML
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html_tag)
doc.children.each do |node|
  if node.name == 'label'
    span = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new "span", doc
    node.add_child(span)
  end
end
```

Comment: Where exactly do you want the new span to show up?

Comment: You need to show an example of what your output/resulting HTML should look like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to add/change/delete HTML:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse('<div class="input">hello</div>')
div = doc.at('div')
div << '<span>Hello</span>'
puts doc.to_html
```

Which results in:

```
# >> <div class="input">hello<span>Hello</span>
# >> </div>
```

Notice that the above code appended a new node to the existing children of the `<div>`, because of [`<<`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-3C-3C), which means they were appended *after* the text-node containing "hello".

If you want to overwrite the children, you can do that easily using [`children =`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-children-3D):

```
div.children = '<span>Hello</span>'
puts doc.to_html
```

Which results in:

```
# >> <div class="input"><span>Hello</span></div>
```

[`children =`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-3C-3C) can take a single Node which can have multiple other nodes nestled under it, or the HTML text of the node(s) being inserted. That's what `node_or_tags` means when you see it in [the documentation](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html).

That said, to change just an embedded `<label>`, I'd do something like:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse('<div class="input"><label>hello</label></div>')
label = doc.at('div label')
label.name = 'span' if label
puts doc.to_html
# >> <div class="input"><span>hello</span></div>
```

Or:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse('<div class="input"><label>hello</label></div>')
label = doc.at('div label')
label.replace("<span>#{ label.text }</span>") if label
puts doc.to_html
# >> <div class="input"><span>hello</span></div>
```

Nokogiri makes it easy to change the tag's name once you've pointed at it. You can easily change the text inside the `<span>` by replacing `#{ label.text }` with whatever you desire.

`at('div label')` is one way of finding a particular node. It basically means "find the first label tag inside the first div". `at` means find the first of something, and is similar to using `search(...).first`. There are CSS and XPath equivalents to both `at` and `search` in the [Nokogiri::XML::Node documentation](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html) if you need those.

Comment: This fixed it, I was using `Nokogiri::XML::` when I should've been using `Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment::`. :-)

Comment: The difference between using `DocumentFragment.parse` and normal parsing is that, in the later, Nokogiri creates a DOM with the surrounding `<html><body>` tags, basically doing fix-ups, in an attempt to create a syntactically correct document.

Comment: Is there anyway to add a parent to a fragment? I need to wrap and iframe in a div and give that div a specific class.

Comment: @ZackHerbert Create a separate question for that. Asking a new question in a comment highjacks the current question and doesn't allow us to answer correctly. See "[ask]" along with the linked pages. Your question is answered in many pages about Nokogiri here, so search before asking. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421

Answer (score 2):

A few issues - you `span = ..` line was creating the node but not actually adding it to the document. Also, you can't access `span` outside of the block where you created it.

I think this is what you're after:

```
html = '<label>Hi</label>'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(html)

doc.children.each do |node|
  if node.name == 'label'
    # this code gets called
    span = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new "span", doc
    span.content = "hello"
    node.add_child(span)
  end
end

# NOTE: `node` nor `span` are accessible outside of the each block

doc.to_s # => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<label>Hi<span>hello</span></label>\n"
```

Note the `node.add_child(span)` line.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry for showing confusing code. The calls to puts (for span) were actually *inside* the block.